# Set default authorizations for an uploaded document

Tags: document-library, file-upload, inheritance, authorization

Is it possible, when you upload a document and put it in a library, to set automatically inherited rights from the library to this document ? Because, for the moment, when I upload a document (during page edit) it set only the administrator and the uploader in the authorizations. How can I resolve this problem ?
Thank you with advance and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create an event receiver in the item adding event, then in that event you can set permissions your self with the SPFolder and SPFile classes.

Here is an example of more or less how can it be done
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robgruen/archive/2007/11/15/how-to-programmatically-set-permissions-on-files-folders-in-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx

how to create an event receiver
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much ! But do you know if there is an easier way to set only inheritance rights ? It's sounds very strange to me that inheritance rights aren't set by default... Thank you again even so !

Comment: actually by default inheritance rights are always Inherited, lol, thats the default behavior, your file will inherit the permissions of your document library, the doc library will inherit the permissions from your site, etc, etc.  However you can break the inheritance manually at any time..

Comment: Yes it is what I don't understand, when I upload a new file during page edit, only two users are set in rights : Portal admin and the uploader (or the creator of the document I don't know) and library have a long list of users inherited from my site... I'm a bit lost :)

Comment: Sorry for my poor english and ambiguities I'm french

Comment: Could it come from the template of the type of document ?